# Nest.js @nestjs/platform-fastify，NestFastifyApplication<RawServerDefault>' does not satisfy the constraint 'INestApplication'

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I'm using Nest.js, and I change express to fastify,but I got this error, NestFastifyApplication' does not satisfy the constraint 'INestApplication', I tried to uninstall @nestjs/platform-fastify, then install again, but still got this error,

this my code:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import {
  FastifyAdapter,
  NestFastifyApplication,
} from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter(),
  );
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

I run `nest info`:

```
[Nest Platform Information]
platform-fastify version : 10.0.3
mapped-types version     : 2.0.2
schematics version       : 9.2.0
testing version          : 9.4.3
common version           : 9.4.3
core version             : 9.4.3
cli version              : 9.5.0
```

I don't know how to solve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`common`, `core`, `platform-fastify`, and `testing` should all be on the same version. `schematics` and `cli` should be on the same major version. That should fix your issue

Comment: McDniel, cool, hats off to you

Answer (score 1):

In your question you should downgrade your @nestjs/platform-fastify version to 9.x.x, alternatively, update the relevant nestjs components to 10.x for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

I update nest cli to v.10 will solve the issue.
Check this document for more.

https://dev.to/amirfakour/how-to-upgrade-nestjs-9-to-10-a-developers-guide-32kk